# passing a function name as parameter in LUA

Tags: function, button, lua, widget

So I have a button class in which I create my button:

```
self.button = widget.newButton {..., onEvent = handleEvent)
```

And I want to call that button class in my main, so i'm doing :

```
local button = Button:new(..., handle)
```

The thing is all my event handler are located in my button class.
How can i pass the name of the event handler from outside the class ?

I can't just pass it as handle neither as "handle" ...
I guess I would have to pass it as a function, but how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Functions in Lua are first class citizens that can be treated like any other values; they can be assigned to variables or passed as function arguments.

```
local function cb() ... end
local button = Button:new(..., cb)
```

Or without a local variable.

```
local button = Button:new(..., function() ... end)
```

If you want to call a method on your button class, you can do that too with a closure:

```
self.button = widget.newButton {..., onEvent = function() return self:onPressed() end)
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work, because the body of my function is in the button class, so bassicaly I just want to send the name of the handler as parameter, so I could have all my handler in my button class.
Or I misunderstood your answer..

Comment: I understand what you're saying but this is not really my trouble.
The thing is I want to give the method name as a parameter.
So in my main I create it: 
local button = Button:new(..., "I want to pass a name here")

and in my button.lua

self.button = widget.newButton {..., onEvent = I want to get my parameter here)

and the handler functions are in the button.lua

i don't know how to explain it, or again, if you actually answered exactly that and i just didn't understand it, which is possible ^^

Comment: So you have a bunch of functions stored in a table in `buttons.lua`, and you want to pass in the name of the function in that table? Doesn't sound like a very good design.

Comment: Is it not ?
I actually thought that would be a good design, having all the functions related to all buttons in one file instead of having to create the functions in the scene file...
Should I do that instead ?
And specifically, why is it bad designing ?

Comment: My take on it is that putting button functions in a single file distances the button function from where it is actually used, and the `buttons.lua` becomes a huge dumping ground of unrelated functions.

Comment: @Néocypher the bad design is not because you have them all in that table (if they're really that related to each other), but because you want to use strings to identify the functions, instead of just passing the function itself as a parameter.